# Routes are not working properly

Tags: laravel

When the user accesses "http://proj.test/" instead of getting the homepage I get:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

But if the user accesses "http://proj.test/home" it works.

Also when the user accesses "http://proj.test/conference/create" instead of appear the page with the form to create a conference it appears:

```
View [app] not found. (View: /Users/johnw/projects/proj/resources/views/conferences/create.blade.php)
```

Do you know where can be the issue? Should be something about the links or routes but I don't know where is the issue.

**Links that I'm using**

```
 <a class="logo" href="{{route('home')}}">Homepage</a>
   <a href="{!! route('conference.create') !!}">Create Conference</a>
   <a href="{{url('/login')}}">Login</a>
   <a href="{{ url('logout') }}">Logout</a>
   <a href="{!! route('register'); !!}">Register</a>
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

        Route::post('/conference/store', [
            'uses' => 'ConferenceController@store',
            'as'   => 'conference.store'
        ]);


        Route::get('/conference/create', [
            'uses' => 'ConferenceController@create',
            'as'   => 'conference.create'
        ]);    
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the user accesses "http://proj.test/" instead of getting the homepage I get:
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

You have not defined any route for this URL
You can do

```
...
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why is necessary to have both routes?

Comment: @johnZ, because there is no route for the '/' under the auth controller. and `/` is the default landing page.

Comment: Thanks, but the rotue: "Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');" is not necessary right? We can have just the route: "Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');"?

Comment: /home is pre set to be the redirected route also. such as the login controller. you'd need both.

Comment: And do you know why accessing "http://proj.test/conference/create" appears "View [app] not found. (View: /Users/johnw/projects/proj/resources/views/conferences/create.blade.php)"?

Comment: View [app] means it's looking for something names `app.blade.php` (if you're using blade).

Comment: Thanks, I have that file in the /views/layouts/app.blade.php.

Comment: Then you need to call `layout.app`, not `app`.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer - you need a `Route::get('/', ...)` route.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Routes instead:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index'); 
   // WelcomeController is my own example, yours will differ...
});
```

This way it'll check to see if there's an auth or not and will redirect accordingly.